# python kivy requests import error,ı have buılozer.spec

Tags: python, python-requests, kivy, buildozer, requirements

I have added the request in the buildozer.spec requirements list but it cannot import at Kivy Launcher ı don't have any issue in terminal
ı am using python 3.7.2 on linux

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

import os
import sys

import requests


class FirstKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hello")

FirstKivy().run()

my logs:
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in/storage/emulated/0/kivy/Project/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-04-28_21.txt
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (21 instead of 14)
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2016, 23:30:13) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/user/0/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: pygame
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     import requests
[WARNING           ] stderr: ImportError: No module named requests
```

Comment: I use this requirements line: `requirements = openssl, python3, kivy, requests, urllib3`. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: @JohnAnderson,No, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy launcher doesn't include requests. Build your own apk using buildozer/python-for-android.

Comment: I understood but I wanna try program at kivy launcher, working or not..., but thank you, any way hasn't in kivy launcher?